# Dapper 'Query' not recognised

Tags: c#

The 'connection.Query' does not prompt for Dapper using statement. Dapper has been installed several times. I've tried entering the using statement 'using Dapper' but it's underlined in red saying:

> Dapper namespace could not be found

Why is it happening?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DataAccessLibrary
{
    public class SQLDataAccess
    {
        public List<T> LoadData<T, U>(string sqlStatement, U parameters, string connectionString)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                List<T> rows = connection.Query<T>(sqlStatement, parameters).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What runtime version is your application targeting? The latest version of Dapper requires .NET Framework 4.6.1 or .NET Standard 2.0. If you're targeting, say, .NET 4.5.1, the reference to Dapper won't work and the namespace won't be recognized. You could downgrade to package version 1.60.6, which does support .NET Framework 4.5.1. It's something to look into and attempt to try to rule out, anyway...

Comment: Try removing the Dapper Nuget package and then reinstalling it, pay careful attention to version numbers

Comment: You should update the code in your question to show what you believe is the correct code: it should include the using statement.

Comment: Hello all, I'm embarrassed to say i installed Dapper into the wrong project in my application. I assumed (never assume, always check) wrongly that the installation would be seen throughout my app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed to say i installed Dapper into the wrong project in my application. I assumed (never assume, always check) wrongly that the installation would be seen throughout my app. 
Problem solved.